# Issue with LINQ IN clause when filter value is empty but works with filter values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a filter called serviceEntryFilter with a property System  which could have values for instance EP1, EP2  OR EP1 and sometimes this filter would be null. If there are multiple values or a single value then the query (IN) clause runs fine . If the filter value is null then I get the following error:

**Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.String[]'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult List(string ServiceEntryStatus, string ServiceEntryReconciled, string ServiceEntryReliabilityRecord, string ActiveServiceEntry,
                                    int PageNo, ServiceEntryFilter serviceEntryFilter = null)
        {


           string[] systems = null;


        var list = (from se in db.ServiceEntry
                    join r in db.RunLogEntry on se.RunLogEntryID equals r.ID into joinRunLogEntry
                    from r2 in joinRunLogEntry.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join u in db.User on se.TechnicianID equals u.ID
                    join s in db.System1 on se.SystemID equals s.ID
                    where (
                        ((se.RunLogEntryID == 0 || se.RunLogEntryID != null))
                             && ((serviceEntryFilter.ID.HasValue == false) || (se.ID == serviceEntryFilter.ID.Value && serviceEntryFilter.ID.HasValue == true))
                            && ((serviceEntryFilter.ServiceDateTime.HasValue == false) || (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(se.ServiceDateTime) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(serviceEntryFilter.ServiceDateTime) && serviceEntryFilter.ServiceDateTime.HasValue == true))
                            && ((serviceEntryFilter.RunDate.HasValue == false) || (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r2.RunDate) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(serviceEntryFilter.RunDate) && serviceEntryFilter.RunDate.HasValue == true))
                            && ((serviceEntryFilter.Technician == null) || (u.FullName.Contains(serviceEntryFilter.Technician.Trim()) && serviceEntryFilter.Technician != null))
                            && (
                                    ((ServiceEntryStatus == "O" && se.ServiceRequestClosed == false) ||
                                      (ServiceEntryStatus == "C" && se.ServiceRequestClosed == true) ||
                                      (ServiceEntryStatus == "A")
                                    )
                               )
                                   && (
                                    ((ServiceEntryReliabilityRecord == null) ||
                                     (ServiceEntryReliabilityRecord == "N" && se.ReliabilityRecord == false) ||
                                      (ServiceEntryReliabilityRecord == "Y" && se.ReliabilityRecord == true) ||
                                      (ServiceEntryReliabilityRecord == "A")
                                    )
                                )
                            && (
                                    ((ServiceEntryReconciled == null) ||
                                     (ServiceEntryReconciled == "N" && se.Reconciled == false) ||
                                      (ServiceEntryReconciled == "Y" && se.Reconciled == true) ||
                                      (ServiceEntryReconciled == "A")
                                    )
                                )
                                         && (
                                    ((ActiveServiceEntry == null) ||
                                     (ActiveServiceEntry == "N" && se.Active == false) ||
                                      (ActiveServiceEntry == "Y" && se.Active == true) ||
                                      (ActiveServiceEntry == "A")
                                    )
                                )

                                    && (
                                  (s.PlatformID == platformID) || (platformID == 0)
                               )
                        && ((serviceEntryFilter.System == null) || ((serviceEntryFilter.System != null) && systems.Contains(s.SystemFullName)))
                       )
                    orderby se.ID descending
                    select new ServiceSearchEntry()
                    {
                        ID = se.ID,
                        ServiceDateTime = se.ServiceDateTime,
                        Technician = u.FullName,
                        System = s.SystemFullName,
                        ReasonForFailure = se.ReasonForFailure,
                        RunDate = (r2 == null ? (DateTime?)null : r2.RunDate)
                    });

        var listData = list.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);

        ServiceEntriesListViewModel viewModel = new ServiceEntriesListViewModel()
        {
            ServiceSearchEntry = listData,
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = list.Count()
            }
        };



}
```

**The Issue:**

The following clause is throwing an error when SystemFilter.System is NULL. It is null at times when users do not select values for it. Sample values are as follows:

EP1, EP2
EP1
TP2, TP3, TP4

**&& ((serviceEntryFilter.System == null) || ((serviceEntryFilter.System != null) && systems.Contains(s.SystemFullName)))**

If it has a value, then I put it in an array and its works like a charm, its just when its null.

Comment: I don't see a a linq query in there.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: I only posted the relevant where clause

Comment: You really should post the entire linq statement. Also, what filter is null? You have `serviceEntryFilter.System` and `systems`. Where is the null value?

Comment: @tamtam If you post incomplete information you won't be able to get the accurate answer.

Comment: well apparently @James was able to answer the question and you are saying I posted incomplete information.

Comment: @tamtam please tell me where the null value is, so I can help

Comment: @James I edited the question and it mentions which value is null

Comment: Is the error not coming from `systems = serviceEntryFilter.System.Split(',');`? Where is this code called from? I think you need to post a bit more.

Comment: guys, I am sorry I will be reformatting the entire question shortly.

Comment: @DaveWilliams I added thorough information in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that everything inside a LINQ statement will get translated to SQL. There isn't really a conditional statement that I see here that says "don't try to add this array filter if it's actually null".

I would initialize the `systems` array to a zero length array, overwrite it if the `filter.Systems` is not null, and then make my linq statement as follows:

`systems.Contains(s.SystemFullName)`

Don't include that null checking inside the LINQ statement as it's not doing what you are expecting.

To build conditional LINQ statements, you might want to look at PredicateBuilder: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: I followed your suggestions by the doing the following :  string[] systems = new string[0];   and the clause:                                                       && (runLogEntryFilter.System == null) || (systems.Contains(s.SystemFullName)).   It works perfect now

Comment: oh sorry i meant the null part was also removed from the query

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx) with Linq to Entities - see section on **Referencing Non-Scalar Variables Not Supported**.

In otherwords, this line:

```
systems.Contains(s.SystemFullName)
```

can't be used as part of your EF query.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. As far as I know, you can reference a string array in a linq statement. I assume `s.SystemFullName` is also a string.

Comment: @Thr33Dii so when I pass the array it searches fine, its just when the value is null then it throws the error. You are are correct s.SystemFullName is a string

Comment: @tamtam what value is null? An item in the array or the array itself?

Comment: well if you look at the clause, the systemfilter.system is null at times because user did not provide values. if the systemfilter.system has values for instance multiple then i split them in an array